# Docker with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am setting up a development environment with the docker. In it I need

- NGINX (webservice)
- PHP 7.2 (app)
- MARIADB 10.3 (database)

In the app container I must install composer, I will work using laravel.

Using `RUN composer install` and`COPY .env.example .env` in `dockerfile` to install `vendor` and configure`.env`, I did not get any error messages but no files were created either.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:7.2
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    networks:
      - app-network


  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client-10.3 \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Run composer install
RUN composer install

# Create the .env from the .env.example
COPY .env.example .env

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: You may also consider [laradock](https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock) that aims to run laravel and everything you could need with docker

Comment: What do you mean by "no files were created either"? They should be present in the built image. Maybe the synchronization of your volume is broken? -- By the way, `COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www` implicitely already performs `COPY . /var/www`, but with the added chown.

Comment: The files I want to create, in this case the copy of .env and the vendor folder that should be created from the "composer install" command are neither in the container nor is it created in my project either.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Setup to deploy a Laravel Application with the help of NGINX Web Server and MYSQL Database at [Github](https://github.com/agarwalvaibhav0211/Dockerize-Laravel-Project-With-MySQL-and-Nginx).
It should be pretty easy to set up. If you encounter any issues, please feel free to raise an issue at Github, or ask me here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer